# Image Vibrating and animations not working css

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, hover

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  const navbar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
  const navbarHeight = 10;

  const distanceFromTop = Math.abs(
    document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top
  );
  if (distanceFromTop >= navbarHeight) navbar.classList.add("nav-bar-fixed");
  else navbar.classList.remove("nav-bar-fixed");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tilt+Neon&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Tilt Neon', cursive;
}

.nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: black 5px solid;
  transition: 2s;
}

.nav-bar-anim {
  height: 12vh;
  transition: 2s;
}

.nav-bar-fixed {
  height: 8vh;
  transition: 2s;
}

.logo {
  width: 110px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.nav-items a {
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/* main-sector  */

.main-section {
  background-image: url(img/famous-japanese-food-sushi.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  background-size: cover;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  position: relative;
}

.main-section .blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}

.main-section a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 4vw;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.main-section .line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: .5%;
  background-color: rgb(150, 29, 29);
  animation: expandline 5s forwards;
}

.second-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  ;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  gap: 40px;
}

.second-section a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.color-change {
  color: black;
  transition: 2s;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav-bar {
    height: 16vh;
  }
  .nav-bar-fixed {
    height: 12vh;
    transition: 2s;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 10%;
  }
  .nav-items {
    gap: 30px;
  }
  .nav-items a {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  .main-section {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.nav-items a:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

@keyframes expandline {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
  <title>Sushi</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav-bar" class="nav-bar-anim" class="nav-bar-anim">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.webp" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="nav-items">
      <a href="">Contact</a>
      <a href="">Order</a>
      <a href="">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-section">



    <div class="blur"></div>
    <div class="line" class="first-line"></div>
    <a href="tel:747-272-2997">Order Now</a>
    <div class="line"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="second-section">
    <h1>Check Out Our Menu</h1>
    <a class="color-change" href="">Menu</a>




  </div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis inventore aspernatur animi veritatis id eius illo, doloremque enim itaque pariatur, nostrum molestiae dolorum beatae delectus rem perspiciatis, deserunt vitae repellendus assumenda atque
  ipsam libero sequi ut consequatur. Laboriosam libero recusandae reiciendis ipsum, harum deleniti itaque doloremque officia praesentium voluptatibus similique dolores? In facilis impedit officia obcaecati ex tempore, quod laboriosam dicta voluptatibus?
  Qui quasi eius debitis! Neque minus maiores voluptates, quas architecto laboriosam perspiciatis explicabo vel quis, voluptas ipsam nemo omnis ipsum nesciunt? A incidunt amet cupiditate odio consectetur aperiam ex animi eum corrupti minus dolorum, doloremque
  cum perspiciatis ad velit quas veritatis labore nisi qu

</body>
<script src="home.js"></script>

</html>
```

I am trying to build a sushi website but my main-section image keeps vibrating when scrolling down in Fullscreen desktop. My nav bar also doesn't work in mobile version when scrolling down the navbar doesn't collapse to be more smaller like in desktop. I am also having issues with making my animations not load when on the website for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

i'd say the mobile version with the navbar not collapsing is because the javascript event listener is not recieving the "scroll" event, maybe it's named as a different event on mobile, or maybe it isn't ever a certain amount of space from the top on mobile? to test this i suggest doing a console.log(space from top or whatever) in the "scroll" event listener. as for the vibrating maybe try proccess of elimination and just delete random stuff from ur css until it works? as for the animation, idrk.

Comment: its collapsing without any animation

Comment: it might be because you've added the nav-bar-anim class twice, also on a different note, when adding two classes you can just say class = "class1 class2" you don't need to have to class assigns you can just have a space between them. another thing i noticed is in the javascript code you are adding the classes every time the scroll event callback is called. a better way to do this is only add and remove the nav-bar-fixed class if the classlist doesn't already contain it.